# Geolocation Keeping the Browser Session Persistent

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, geolocation

I am working on a geolocation project that is browser-based and geared specifically towards mobile browsers. I won't go deep into details but overall the project uses geolocation across many pages and pieces of the project. The problem as it seems is that despite hitting "accept" and "allow" always on any given browser, when the user reloads a page they are prompted almost everytime to reallow the location authentication.

Which to me is weird, I've gone to sites with geolocation on it that it truly remembers that I allowed it, even if for the duration of me being on the site and not always. So with that I am wondering is there some type of special thing I need to do to store this authentication for a prolonged period on my project?

Currently I am using javascript-based geolocation through the google maps API and newer browser support for non ip based location. My project at the users discretion tracks where they are so other people connected to them can see where they are, where they have been, or where they plan to go (if they enter that in). There's more as well, but that's the basics. From a UX perspective, it's annoying to have to prompt my users every time the browser reloads to reauth the location.

So any advice anyone is able to give, or insight on how to handle this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Cookies** and **sessions**.

Right after detecting the user geo-location you should store it in a Cookie.
Every request from the server should look if there is a cookie set (with the user's location) and act upon it.

Over-simplified code:

```
// get user location (via javascript)
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) 
{
  initialLocation = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude,position.coords.longitude);
}

// ajax the server with the user location
$.post('ajax/set_user_location.php', initialLocation);
```

Then on the server you grab the `initialLocation` and save it in a cookie.

Comment: Indeed helpful, and I will have to use this, but I am curious how this can tie into those who are moving about? Im not looking to track every footstep, i'd likely very well need GPS for that, but if someone goes from point a to point b, and comes back while they are still logged in, I'd like to find the new current location, is this possible or would the browser need to reauthenticate the permission at a browser level? Essentially meaning its something out of my control

Comment: @chris, I would personally have it perform this way. The server will then ID the client and "assume" a position. As the client runs the code javascript would check the actual position and, if it had changed, would contact the server for an update. The re-check code would be lazy (non-blocking, low-priority) and would run every hour, minute, 10% of the time, that would really depend on the site/app.